# How to execute an SQL query from file in Airflow? (PostgresSQL operator)

Tags: python, postgresql, jinja2, airflow

I am using PostgresSQL Operator. The task is the following:

```
emailage_transformations = PostgresOperator(
    task_id = 'emailage_transformations',
    sql = '/home/ubuntu/airflow_ci/current/scripts/antifraud/emailage_transformations.sql',
    postgres_conn_id = 'redshift',
    autocommit = True,
    dag = dag)
```

At first, the content of the file was the next:

```
select cd_pedido_nr,fraud_score,risk_band,ip_risk_level
into antifraud.stg_emailage_id_pedido
from antifraud.stg_emailage_id_email e
left join antifraud.info_emails i on id_email = cd_email_nr
;
```

And the error I got was

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: /home/ubuntu/airflow_ci/current/scripts/antifraud/emailage_transformations.sql
```

So I have added a couple of brackets to the query for complying with jinja2 templating and now the file code is:

```
{select cd_pedido_nr,fraud_score,risk_band,ip_risk_level
into antifraud.stg_emailage_id_pedido
from antifraud.stg_emailage_id_email e
left join antifraud.info_emails i on id_email = cd_email_nr
;}
```

However, I still have the same error. How could I solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recon as told in following links, you ought to provide a [`template_searchpath`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dag.py#L105) to your DAG so as to enable it picking your external files (SQL or other files)

- [External files in Airflow DAG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46091929/3679900)
- [How to pass SQL as file with parameters to Airflow Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52691700/3679900)
- [Template_searchpath gives TemplateNotFound error in Airflow and cannot find the SQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56457599/3679900)

Alternatively making external file discoverable, such as [by modifying `AIRFLOW_HOME`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42984459/3679900) or through [other tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57693865/3679900) can also work

Comment: The default template searchpath is the folder where the dag itself is stored, so if the file is in the same folder than the DAG, you don't have to provide a template searchpath

Answer (score 0):

For default Airflow operators, file paths **must** be relative (to the DAG folder or to the DAG's `template_searchpath` property).
But if you really need to use absolute paths, this can be achieved like this:

```py
import pendulum

from airflow.decorators import dag
from airflow.providers.common.sql.operators.sql import SQLExecuteQueryOperator


class TestSqlOperator(SQLExecuteQueryOperator):
    def render_template_fields(self, context, jinja_env=None) -> None:
        if not jinja_env:
            jinja_env = self.get_template_env()
            if isinstance(jinja_env.loader.searchpath, list):
                jinja_env.loader.searchpath.append('/')
        super().render_template_fields(context=context, jinja_env=jinja_env)


@dag(
    schedule=None,
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    catchup=False
)
def abs_path_sql_dag():
    TestSqlOperator(
        task_id="sql_op_abs_path",
        conn_id="<your_connection_id>",
        sql="/your/absolute/file/path.sql"
    )


abs_path_sql_dag()
```